# Displaying rows and drawers with PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

A list of items that I am tying to display in rows of 3, after every row of 3 create a drawer with more information about the 3 items that was echoed on the previous row. Where I have problems is that if the row is != 3 the drawers won't display.

For example if i have 4 list items the second row drawer wont display because the 2nd row don't have 3 list items.

1- I want the drawer to be echo even if the row only has 1 item.

My code:

```
<ul class="categories_list">
    <?php 

        $cat_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories where feature=1") or die( mysql_error());
        $row_count = mysql_num_rows($cat_sql);

        $rows = 0;
        $cat_list = array();
        while($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($cat_sql)){
    ?>
        <li class="animated">
            <a href="#<?php echo $cat['id'] ?>" class="main_buttons">
            <span class="category_list_titles">
                <table width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="150" align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $cat['name'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php
            $cat_list[] = array('id'=>$cat['id'], 'name'=>$cat['name']);
            $rows++;

            if($rows == 3) {
                echo '</ul>';
                $rows=0;
                echo '<ul class="categories_list">';
            }

        } 

    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: "second row drawer wont display because the 2nd row don't have 3 list items." The code you've posted doesn't appear to support that claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if the row is divisible by 3, so it will print after every 3rd row.

```
if($rows % 3 == 0)
```

Then, you'll want to use the drawer code again at the very end after the while loop is done, if the final $rows is not divisible by 3, so you don't get the drawer twice in a row.

```
if($rows % 3 != 0)
```

This way, if you have 10 rows, you'll have 3 rows, 1 drawer, 3 rows, 1 drawer, 3 rows, 1 drawer, 1 row, 1 drawer.

Answer (score 0):

```
                if($rows == 3)
                {
                    echo '</ul>';
                    $rows=0;
                    echo '<ul class="categories_list">';
                }
```

I'm going to assume that this controls when the list is generated, right now it only displays if there are exactly 3 rows. So maybe

```
                if(is_numeric($rows))
                {
                    echo '</ul>';
                    $rows=0;
                    echo '<ul class="categories_list">';
                }
```

this will do it. Since you want rows displayed for ANY value you simply need to see if $rows is a number.

Comment: that will display the drawer after every item. the drawer should display after every 3 items, and if the row has 1 or 2 item display it anyways.
[code](
<li>item</li> <li>item</li> <li>item</li>
<div class="drawer"></div>

<li>item</li>)